# Time crime real estate division

Tags: time-travel, money

I've become interested in time crime recently, but I want to muse over how it would work. Someone suggested using future knowledge to invest in real estate might be a good way to make money off time travel. But what I want to know is how someone could intervene in this sort of crime. My current idea is the hero swapped out the information for false copies but that doesn't feel like enough. Is there such a thing where real estate can lose value unexpectedly?

Comment: I think we need to better understand how time travel works in your world to give a good answer.  Is this a multi world time travel, where time travel creates a new world, or one where you change someone's past?  If you can change your past is time travel regulated in general, not just for this kind of 'fraud'?  How easy is time travel?  Seems if you can do it at all there are even easier options to become rich, like lotto tickets or making your own collectable objects, so why would this be the path people would take etc?

Comment: *"Is there such a thing where real estate can lose value unexpectedly?"* I don't know, for example, how much was worth an appartment building on [Nevsky Prospect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevsky_Prospect) in 1910, and how much in 1920? How much was worth the [Villa of the Mysteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villa_of_the_Mysteries) in 78 CE, and how much in 80 CE? How much was an acre of land near [Leptis Magna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leptis_Magna) in the 3rd century CE, and how much is it in the 21st century? In general, has anybody ever lost money on a real estate scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the nature of the timestream in your setting. Traveling back into the past is going to disrupt things grossly unless the special rules of time travel prevent this.

1. Time traveler collects 2023 stock market data, travels back in time to 2003.
2. Time traveler invests in the right kind of companies to get rich. Especially data about the 2008 crisis should allow a killing. (What to buy or sell short, etc.)
3. Time traveler is a multi-billionaire by 2010, and the next decade happens differently. So how did the stock market data work?

Same thing with real estate.

1. Time traveler collects 2023 and 2003 real estate prices and travels back in time to 2003.
2. Time traveler invests in real estate with spectacular price hikes over the next couple of decades.
3. Time traveler finds out that his plots of land went up because historically, someone else bought them *and developed them*.

So the opponent could find out where the time traveler invested, and then steer investment elsewhere.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Don't directly attack the data, but what made it valuable in the first place. Like if the real estate was valuable because of a casino opening up near it, you prevent the casino from opening or give someone else the same data so they open hotels near the casino before they can even start

Comment: @JoeSmith, even worse: Property increased in value because a skilled developer developed *this property*. If a time criminal reads the raw numbers, steps in, and does not have the same *touch* to attract business, the property will falter.

Answer (score 3):

Confiscate the property as abandoned in the time traveler's absence